# Numpy shape function

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
    A = np.array([
            [-1, 3],
            [3, 2]
        ], dtype=np.dtype(float))
    
    b = np.array([7, 1], dtype=np.dtype(float))
    

    print(f"Shape of A: {A.shape}")
    print(f"Shape of b: {b.shape}")
```

Gives the following output :

```
Shape of A: (2, 2)
Shape of b: (2,)
```

I was expecting shape of b to be (1,2) which is one row and two columns, why is it (2,) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect, `b` only has one dimension, not two.

```
b.ndim
# 1
```

To have a 2D array you would have needed an extra set of square brackets:

```
b = np.array([[7, 1]], dtype=np.dtype(float))

b.shape
# (1, 2)

b.ndim
# 2
```

Similarly for a 3D array:

```
b = np.array([[[7, 1]]], dtype=np.dtype(float))

b.shape
# (1, 1, 2)

b.ndim
# 3
```

Note that you can transform your original `b` into a 2D array with:

```
b = np.array([7, 1], dtype=np.dtype(float))

b.shape = (1, 2)

b
# array([[7., 1.]])
```

Or:

```
b = np.array([7, 1], dtype=np.dtype(float))[None]

b.shape
# (1, 2)

b
# array([[7., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you , I think in your third solution you missed adding 2 square brackets ?

Comment: @user1965449 no, this one reshapes by assigning to `b.shape`: `b.shape = (1, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **reshape()**

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([7, 1],dtype=np.float64)
b = b.reshape(1, -1)  
print(f"Shape of b: {b.shape}")  # Output: (1, 2)
```

Or you can try with **newaxis()**

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([7, 1], dtype=np.float64)
b = b[np.newaxis, :]  # Add a new axis to create a row vector
print(f"Shape of b: {b.shape}")  # Output: (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you , I think I could have achieved the same result with b.reshape(1,2) instead or b.reshape(1,-1) ?